# How to override code of module in custom module?

Tags: 7

I am using [Content Taxonomy](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy) module and trying to override some code, when I tried to modify in my custom module then the module functions also keeps running. And by modifying module file my purpose get solved but is there any way to do it in my custom module, please suggest:

CODE NEED TO MODIFIED:

```
/**
 * Form element validate handler for taxonomy term autocomplete element, which denies any new terms.
 */
function content_taxonomy_autocomplete_validate_deny_new_terms($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  $values = $form_state['values'];
  foreach ($element['#array_parents'] as $parent) {
    $values = $values[$parent];
  }
  foreach ($values as $delta => $value) {
    if ($value['tid'] == 'autocreate') {
      form_error($element, t('%name: new terms are not allowed. Please choose from the given list.', array('%name' => $element['#title'])));
    }
  }
}
```

DOING LIKE BELOW:

```
function custom_overrides_field_attach_form($entity_type, $entity, &$form, &$form_state, $langcode) {
  // Add validation function to taxonomy_autocompletes, if necessary.
  $instances = field_info_instances($form['#entity_type'], $form['#bundle']);
  foreach ($instances as $instance) {
    if (($instance['widget']['type'] == 'taxonomy_autocomplete' || $instance['widget']['type'] == 'autocomplete_deluxe_taxonomy') 
      && isset($form[$instance['field_name']]) 
      && isset($instance['widget']['settings']['content_taxonomy_autocomplete_new_terms'])) {

      // Use the language that is used in this form (which doesn't necessarily
      // be the default language in $langcode).
      $lang_key = $form[$instance['field_name']]['#language'];
      if ($instance['widget']['settings']['content_taxonomy_autocomplete_new_terms'] == 'moderate') {
        $form[$instance['field_name']][$lang_key]['#element_validate'][] = 'content_taxonomy_autocomplete_validate_moderate_new_terms';
      }
      else if ($instance['widget']['settings']['content_taxonomy_autocomplete_new_terms'] == 'deny') {
        $form[$instance['field_name']][$lang_key]['#element_validate'][] = 'custom_content_taxonomy_autocomplete_validate_deny_new_terms';
        var_dump($form[$instance['field_name']]);
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Form element validate handler for taxonomy term autocomplete element, which denies any new terms.
 */
function custom_content_taxonomy_autocomplete_validate_deny_new_terms($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  global $user;
       if($element['#title'] == "Topic"){
          if (!$user->uid) {
                $values = $form_state['values'];
                foreach ($element['#array_parents'] as $parent) {
                  $values = $values[$parent];
                }
                foreach ($values as $delta => $value) {
                  if ($value['tid'] == 'autocreate') {
                     form_error($element, t('%name: new terms are not allowed. Please choose from the given list.', array('%name' => $element['#title'])));
                  }
                }
            }
      }else{
            $values = $form_state['values'];
            foreach ($element['#array_parents'] as $parent) {
              $values = $values[$parent];
            }
            foreach ($values as $delta => $value) {
              if ($value['tid'] == 'autocreate') {
                form_error($element, t('%name: new terms are not allowed. Please choose from the given list.', array('%name' => $element['#title'])));
              }
            }
      }
 }
```

By Doing this now I have my custom validator running and my custom module weight is 1000 and contrib module weight is 0 but still its not working because I think second validator function as shown below in output of var_dump need to be unset by some way:

```
'#element_validate' => 
        array (size=3)
          0 => string 'taxonomy_autocomplete_validate' (length=30)
          1 => string 'content_taxonomy_autocomplete_validate_deny_new_terms' (length=53)
          2 => string 'custom_content_taxonomy_autocomplete_validate_deny_new_terms' (length=60)
```

Comment: You Can able to create a custom patch file, only includes the changes that you need to modify.
how to create a patch refer : https://www.drupal.org/node/707484

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way that I can modify it with help of custom module so that while updating module I dont have to take care of patch file ?

Comment: I don't think we can redeclare functions, its already in used module file

Comment: @Vicky8888: template.php is only for theme overrides and certain hooks.

Comment: Just checking, is your module called 'custom_overrides'?

Comment: Have you tried placing dpm or print_r everywhere to check up to what point your code is executed?

Comment: problem is as shown in screenshot it runs and second validator function does not let it go to mine custom one ie: 3rd one. Is there some way so that I can unset 'content_taxonomy_autocomplete_validate_deny_new_terms' added by contirb module and just run mine one 'custom_content_taxonomy_autocomplete_validate_deny_new_terms'

Comment: Ah right, images are blocked here so I'm not able to see yours. In my answer below I provided an example how to remove the old validation function.

Comment: I am lookin at your one and try I have removed image and added code to show how validators are added. @rooby said exactly same thing that it got added at last but I am not sure how to unset previous one or replace like you also said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Shabir A. you can also unset the original validation function.

For this, your module needs to run after the contrib module. You can achieve this by altering your module's weight.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_attach_form().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_field_attach_form($entity_type, $entity, &$form, &$form_state, $langcode) {
  // Add validation function to taxonomy_autocompletes, if necessary.
  $instances = field_info_instances($form['#entity_type'], $form['#bundle']);
  foreach ($instances as $instance) {
    if (($instance['widget']['type'] == 'taxonomy_autocomplete' || $instance['widget']['type'] == 'autocomplete_deluxe_taxonomy') 
      && isset($form[$instance['field_name']]) 
      && isset($instance['widget']['settings']['content_taxonomy_autocomplete_new_terms'])) {

      // Use the language that is used in this form (which doesn't necessarily
      // be the default language in $langcode).
      $lang_key = $form[$instance['field_name']]['#language'];
      if ($instance['widget']['settings']['content_taxonomy_autocomplete_new_terms'] == 'moderate') {
        $form[$instance['field_name']][$lang_key]['#element_validate'][] = 'content_taxonomy_autocomplete_validate_moderate_new_terms';
      }
      else if ($instance['widget']['settings']['content_taxonomy_autocomplete_new_terms'] == 'deny') {
        // Loop through existing validation functions.
        foreach ($form[$instance['field_name']][$lang_key]['#element_validate'] as $key => $val) {
          // If we find the old one, unset it.
          if ($val == 'content_taxonomy_autocomplete_validate_deny_new_terms') {
            unset($form[$instance['field_name']][$lang_key]['#element_validate'][$key]);
          }
        }

        // Add your own validation function.
        $form[$instance['field_name']][$lang_key]['#element_validate'][] = 'YOUR_VALIDATION_FUNCTION';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try array_search() for locating the #element_validate array item to override/unset.

Comment: I missed part in your code thats was showing how to unset previous validator!. Thank you for help !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [hook_field_attach_form().](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_form/7) function much like it has been done in content_taxonomy_autocomplete module and replace the validate function to the one you want.

```
function MODULENAME_field_attach_form($entity_type, $entity, &$form, &$form_state, $langcode) {
 // Add validation function to taxonomy_autocompletes, if necessary.
  $instances = field_info_instances($form['#entity_type'], $form['#bundle']);
  foreach ($instances as $instance) {
    if (($instance['widget']['type'] == 'taxonomy_autocomplete' || $instance['widget']['type'] == 'autocomplete_deluxe_taxonomy') 
      && isset($form[$instance['field_name']]) 
      && isset($instance['widget']['settings']['content_taxonomy_autocomplete_new_terms'])) {

      // Use the language that is used in this form (which doesn't necessarily
      // be the default language in $langcode).
      $lang_key = $form[$instance['field_name']]['#language'];
      if ($instance['widget']['settings']['content_taxonomy_autocomplete_new_terms'] == 'moderate') {
        $form[$instance['field_name']][$lang_key]['#element_validate'][] = 'content_taxonomy_autocomplete_validate_moderate_new_terms';
      }
      else if ($instance['widget']['settings']['content_taxonomy_autocomplete_new_terms'] == 'deny') {
        $form[$instance['field_name']][$lang_key]['#element_validate'][] = 'YOUR_NEW_VALIDATOR_NAME';
      }
    }
  }

}


// add your validater function here
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I did but the function in module also runs and my custom module theme also runs, I am not sure how to make run my function in custom module only. Is we need to assign high weight to custom module, please suggest ?

Comment: Custom module always have top priority, to make it sure. you can check in system table. if it has less priority increase the weight column.

Comment: The reason that the other function still runs is because this code adds the new validate function to the end of the #element_validate array. It needs to replace the existing value with the new one. Check out the php function array_search() for finding the key to replace.
You will also need to make sure your module runs after the content_taxonomy_autocomplete module's hook implementation, so check out hook_module_implements_alter() for that (changing the module's weight is an alternative to hook_module_implements_alter()).

Comment: Your "// add your validater function here" comment is in the wrong place. It should be outside the last closing brace.

Comment: You also shouldn't be doing anything for the new terms #element_validate since you don't want to override that.

Comment: Thanks all, I have updated my question, how I am trying now. Please suggest what I am doing wrong